# NoMethodError - undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, maps, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm pretty new to Rails and building a store locator app using a maps API. I have a Store model and a Toilet model that are associated so that users can selected if a store has a toilet or not when they are adding a store. However, I keep getting the following error when I try and add a store and select "no" for toilet_available:

```
NoMethodError in Stores#create
Showing /mnt/c/Users/Me/Dropbox/coding/SpaetiApp/app/views/stores/_form.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #7):
5
6
7
8
9
10

    <%= f.input :address_line3, label: "Country", input_html: { value: "Germany"} %>
    <%= f.input :beer_cost, label: "Cost of a Berliner Pilsner" %>
    <%= select_tag(:toilet_id, options_for_select(@toilets), :prompt => "Toilet available?" ) %>
    <%= f.input :facilities, label: "Facilities" %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/stores/new.html.erb
```

I don't get this error when I select "yes" for toilet_available, however. Here are the relevant files.

stores controller:

```
class StoresController < ApplicationController

    before_action :find_store, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        if params[:toilet].blank?
            @stores = Store.all.order("created_at DESC")
        else
            @toilet_id = Toilet.find_by(toilet_available: params[:toilet]).id
          @stores = Store.where(:toilet_id => @toilet_id).order("created_at DESC")
        end
    end

    def show
    end

    def edit
        @toilets = Toilet.all.map{ |t| [t.toilet_available, t.id] }
    end

    def update
        @store.toilet_id = params[:toilet_id] 
        if @store.update(store_params)
            redirect_to store_path(@store)
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

    def new
        @store = current_user.stores.build
        @toilets = Toilet.all.map{ |t| [t.toilet_available, t.id] }
    end

    def create
        @store = current_user.stores.build(store_params)
        @store.toilet_id = params[:toilet_id] 

        if @store.save 
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @store.destroy
        redirect_to root_path
    end

    private

        def store_params
            params.require(:store).permit(:name, :address, :address_line2, :address_line3, :beer_cost, :toilet_id)
        end

        def find_store
            @store = Store.find(params[:id])
        end
end
```

Schema.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20180814220216) do

  create_table "stores", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "address"
    t.float "beer_cost"
    t.text "facilities"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    t.boolean "toilet"
    t.string "address_line2"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "toilet_id"
    t.string "address_line3"
  end

  create_table "toilets", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "toilet_available"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @store,:html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: "Spaeti Name" %>
    <%= f.input :address, label: "Address" %>
    <%= f.input :address_line2, label: "City", input_html: { value: "Berlin" } %>
    <%= f.input :address_line3, label: "Country", input_html: { value: "Germany"} %>
    <%= f.input :beer_cost, label: "Cost of a Berliner Pilsner" %>
    <%= select_tag(:toilet_id, options_for_select(@toilets), :prompt => "Toilet available?" ) %>
    <%= f.input :facilities, label: "Facilities" %>

    <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: which file and which line exactly contains the error ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick It is mentioned in the error message. :)

Comment: @StreamedLine How come a view error will happen from rails console. The question you asked useless in this context.

Comment: Shouldn't be the attribute 'toilet_available' in the toilet table a boolean instead of a string? This way, users can easily click a check box or even just a custom link to tell if there is an toilet. Seems for me much more less complicated mapping through attributes? Also, this way you could let users add a integer for a rating of the quality for the toilet, as an example. Just as a tip how i would approach this. Anyway, someone got an answer below that should do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it hits the create action it looks like '@store.save' is returning false and so it's rendering the 'new' template. However, the @toilets variable is not being set in the create action so the template sees it as nil.

Add this line to your create action as well and that will remove the error you're seeing:

```
@toilets = Toilet.pluck(:toilet_available, :id)
```

You could also set it in a before_action for the actions you wanted:

```
before_action :set_toilets, except: [:show, :index]

private

def set_toilets 
  @toilets = Toilet.pluck(:toilet_available, :id) 
end
```

Comment: Instead of map, use pluck:
@toilets = Toilet.all.pluck(:toilet_available, :id)

Comment: This is the correct answer. The action will render the `new` view, when the save fails. So `@toilets` has to be defined in the `create` action.

Comment: Updated it to use pluck. Thanks @GrahamSlick

Comment: It should be `before_action :set_toilets, except: [:show, :index]`

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that `Toilet.all.pluck` is equivalent to `Toilet.pluck`